# Calculus I. Finding $\delta$ for a given $\epsilon(=0.1)$ in $\lim\limits_{x\to -2} \sqrt{1-4x}=3$ (Check my error)

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

> Problem:
>   Find $\delta$ such that $x\to a$ with $0 < |x − a| < \delta$ implies that $|f (x) − L| < \epsilon$ where $\epsilon = 0.1$. (Use a graphing device)

$\lim\limits_{x\to -2} \sqrt{1-4x}=3$

Here are my steps: 
$\lim\limits_{x\to -2} \sqrt{1-4x}=3$
$|\sqrt{1-4x}-3|<\frac{1}{10} $ ($|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$)
$|\sqrt{1-4x}| < \frac{31}{10}$ (discard -3) 
$|1-4x|<\frac{961}{100}$ (cancel the square root) 
$|-4x|<\frac{861}{100}$ 
$|x| < \frac{861}{400}$ 
$|x-(-2)| < \frac{861}{400} -(-2)$ $\leftarrow|x-a|<\delta$ 
Take $\delta$ as $\frac{1661}{400}$(4.1525), while the standard answer is $\delta=\frac{59}{400}$.

Whether I did something wrong with the cancelling? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to find $\delta>0$ such that $|x+2|< \delta$ then $|\sqrt{1-4x}-3|<\frac1{10}$.

That is we want to ensure that

$$-\frac1{10}<\sqrt{1-4x}-3<\frac{1}{10}$$

$$3-\frac1{10}<\sqrt{1-4x}<3+\frac{1}{10}$$

$$(3-\frac1{10})^2<1-4x<(3+\frac{1}{10})^2$$

$$(3-\frac1{10})^2-1<-4x<(3+\frac{1}{10})^2-1$$

$$\frac{(3+\frac{1}{10})^2-1}{-4}<x<\frac{(3-\frac1{10})^2-1}{-4}$$

$$\frac{(3+\frac{1}{10})^2-1}{-4}+2<x+2<\frac{(3-\frac1{10})^2-1}{-4}+2$$

$$-0.1525<x+2<0.1475$$

Hence to make sure that the condition above happens,

we can choose $|x+2|<0.1475$.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I noticed that I forgot to change the direction of the inequality symbol... But anyways the standard answer is wrong right?

Comment: I made a mistake earlier, the standard anwer was correct.

Comment: Oh my that solves my question, thanks a lot!!